# get URL, get Title by Javascript not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get, title

Does anyone know how to get url and title of the current page by using Javascript without jQuery!?

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
  var url = document.location.href
  socializ(encodeURIComponent('+href+'),encodeURIComponent('+title+'))
</script>
```

Just doesn't work.. need help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) is what you're after for the URL piece:

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
```

And for the title, [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title):

```
var title = document.title;
```

Comment: thx but what is wrong here then: <script type="text/javascript">
var href = window.location.href;
var title = window.location.title;
socializ(encodeURIComponent('+href+'),encodeURIComponent('+title+'))
</script>

Comment: @venom use `document.title` for the title :)

Answer (score 4):

`window.location.href` for the URL and `document.title` for the title.

Answer (score 2):

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
var url = document.location.href;
```